# C++ Operator overloading - uni quiz answer looks wrong?

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword, non-member-functions

[image: screenshot]

Hi all

There are have been some mistakes on our uni coursenotes this year and I'm just going over quizzes for revision before exams, the attached pic shows the correct answer for "which cannot be implemented as non-member operator overloading.

Posting on here as may not get answer from uni forum in time. Am I misunderstanding something, or is the answer below wrong?

Thanks :)

Comment: The answer marked correct is, indeed, correct.

Comment: This suspiciously looks like you're trying to get people here to agree with you so you can show your teacher. Tough luck though - the quiz answer seems correct from first glance.

Comment: Why does it "look wrong"? Provide reasoning for your position. (This allows verification and/or rebuttals based on asserted facts.)

Comment: Pray tell, how would this overload be called?

Comment: I guess my questions is really, if d wouldn't work as a non-member function, then surely c wouldn't either? I should have asked, can c) work as non-member function?

Comment: Definitely not @Benjamin.  It's not my current teacher's fault, but he's taken over from someone else and there have been some glaring errors on the notes. Such as describing 2 opposite rotations in  AVL trees, but the code for both is the same. Or that you should use polymorphism instead of type_ids to TEST types....

Comment: Ah, I get it.  I couldn't see it for looking. Revising for an exam and just tired after having to constantly be on the watch out for errors all through this semester of algorithms and data structures. 9/10 when something has frustrated me because it didn't make sense, it has actually been an error
Thanks heaps guys!

Comment: why it is upvoted? a homework to do, in addition with incorrect assumption and lack of reasoning

Answer (score 1):

A non-member function *operator* must consist of two arguments. All the options have two arguments other than the last, so d is the answer. If it were made as a member function or a regular function with a name, it would've compiled.

Answer (score 1):

Binary operators like `operator >` always needs 2 arguments to work. However, member functions get `this` which acts as the first argument. Non-members of course *do not get* `this` and that's why the signature must accept *two* parameters.

So "d" is correct for your "multiple-guess" question above.